# My PHP foreach commands only act on the last item of the array!

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I'm taking the input from a text field, turning each line into a value in an array, and then using a foreach loop to run a search and replace on each value. Code is as follows:

```
$countryinp = trim($_POST['country']);
$countryinp = explode("\n", $countryinp);
$countryinp = array_filter($countryinp, 'trim');
foreach($countryinp as $code)
{
$country = '';
if( $code == 'Afghanistan' ) $country = 'AF';
if( $code == 'Aland Islands' ) $country = 'AX';
if( $code == 'Albania' ) $country = 'AL';
if( $code == 'Algeria' ) $country = 'DZ';
...
if( $country == '') $country = $code;
echo "$country";
echo "<br />";
unset($code);
}
```

The code will loop and output a list of all the inputs, but it only sets `$country` to a two letter code for the last line of the input! I'm going crazy, anyone seen this before?

Comment: `var_dump($countryinp);` before your `foreach` to make sure it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: I'm not sure 'trim' is really an appropriate callback function for array_filter.

Comment: @Frank: Good catch. All that line will accomplish is removing elements that only contain trimmable characters. I don't think it's doing what OP thinks it's doing.

Comment: I think @FrankFarmer makes a good point about `array_walk` and I've updated my answer to describe how this could be causing you issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem are you having exactly? You say that it only sets `$country` to a two-letter code for the last line, but is it printing out all of the codes before that?

This should be obvious, but if you're only having problems with the value of `$country` after the loop finishes, then you should realize that the `$country` variable is overwritten on each iteration of the loop, and would therefore only hold the value from the last iteration when the loop finishes.

If the problem is that your loop isn't *printing* each code, then that sounds like it's a data problem, and you would need to show us the values in your array in order to determine the problem.

One possible data problem you may have is this line:

```
$countryinp = array_filter($countryinp, 'trim');
```

I think your intent with this line is to apply the `trim` function to each element in the array, but that's not what `array_filter` does. The function of `array_filter` is to pass each element in an array to a callback function. That function examines the contents of the element, then returns `true` if the contents should be kept, or `false` if that element should be filtered out of the array.

When you pass `trim` to `array_filter`, the only thing that happens is that any array element which is empty, or only contains whitespace, will be removed. This is because after such elements are trimmed, they are empty. PHP interprets an empty string as `false` and removes it from the array.

This could cause issues with your `if` statements, because if `$code` contains, for example, "Afghanistan " (note the trailing space), then it wouldn't get caught by the `if` statement as the strings wouldn't match.

You would be much better off simply running the line `$code = trim($code);` at the beginning of your `foreach` loop.

Also, your code is a little bit ugly to me. If you're just going to check the same variable over and over (i.e. repeated `if ($code == 'Value')` statements), then you should really be using a [`switch`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement instead:

```
switch ($code) {
    case "Afghanistan":
        $country = 'AF';
        break;
    case "Aland Islands":
        $country ='AX';
        break;
    // repeat for other cases
    default:
        $country = $code;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to copy my `switch` :D

Comment: @webarto: Are you referring to the missing string terminators? I fixed that. Is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: That was the magic bullet! I didn't think of putting `trim()` in each loop! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: @Chris You're welcome, but @Frank Farmer deserves a lot of the credit for noticing the `array_filter` line. I'd glossed over it entirely on my first read through.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
foreach($countryinp as $code)
{
$code = trim($code);
    switch($code){
        case "Afganistan": $country = "AF"; break;
        case "Alanad Islands": $country = "AX"; break;
        default: $country = $code;
    }

    echo $country."<br />";
}
```

And make sure your data exists...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by data exists. I used the switch function and got rid of the `array_filter()` and `unset()` and it's still only applying to the last item in the array! When I `var_dump()` the array it looks fine and all the values are in the correct format.

Comment: It probably means.. make sure $countryinp actually contains... data. :P

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, meaning check if your $countryinp is like you want it to be, meaning var_dump or print_r... @Anther, exactly :)

Comment: I think I might have found the issue. I noticed in `var_dump()` that there are trailing spaces in all but the the last value of the array. Is there an easy way to remove that space?

Comment: @Chris Patten, Yes, in foreach just add `$code = trim($code);` right after `{`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can too many logical issues with this piece of code

```
foreach($countryinp as $code) // #1
{
$country = ''; // #2
if( $code == 'Afghanistan' ) $country = 'AF'; // #3
if( $code == 'Aland Islands' ) $country = 'AX';
if( $code == 'Albania' ) $country = 'AL';
if( $code == 'Algeria' ) $country = 'DZ';
...
if( $country == '') $country = $code; #4
echo "$country";
echo "<br />";
unset($code); // #5
}
```

1. $code is variable visible in foreach
   scope, assigned with value of
   next($countryinp) (pointer to next
   element in array)
2. $country is reset to '' (empty
   value) on each iteration (you are
   resetting $country value)
3. $code == 'xxxx' - here you can use
   switch() statement, two benefits: 1)
   expression is evaluated only once
   then matched against 'case' and 2)
   maintainability (if you have to
   change something in your code...
   Better solution would be to simply
   have array with country name as key
   and country code as value, then you
   can directly access the country code
   like this
   $countryCodes[$countryName];
4. Here you assign current country
   $code to $country only if $country
   is empty but as mantioned in #2 you
   are resetting $country value on each
   iteraction
5. Here you unset the value of $code
   and this is not necessary, $code is
   only visible inside foreach() and
   automatically unset when your code
   exists the foreach loop.

Hope that helps. :)